# How do I run a system command and capture the output with Julia?

Tags: julia

How do I run a system command and capture the output with Julia?

In R I could do this with something like `system_output <- system2("ls","-l", stdout=TRUE, stderr=TRUE)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`read`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.read) function with a [`Cmd`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Cmd) object.  The [docstrings](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.read) are a little hard to find, so here they are:

---

> ```
> read(command::Cmd)
> ```
>
> Run `command` and return the resulting output as an array of bytes.

---

> ```
> read(command::Cmd, String)
> ```
>
> Run `command` and return the resulting output as a `String`.

---

For example, if you want to get the output of `ls -l` as a string, you would run

```
read(`ls -l`, String)
```

The backticks create the `Cmd` object, which is executed by `read`.

Comment: Also see `chomp`, and `@>` from Lazy.jl.